# Form reload in EXTJS4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a form with a save, clear and reload button. The clear button works by clearing the form, using the reset method. But on clicking, the reload button, the form should be loaded back with the data that was typed in the form before clicking the clear button. So, how could this be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Check out `loadRecord()` method:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-loadRecord

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the form's [getValues()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-getValues) and [setValues()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-setValues) methods. When the clear button is clicked, you can use `var oldValues = form.getValues()` to store the current field values. Then when the reload button is clicked, you can restore the values via `form.setValues(oldValues)`.